# How to speed up my MySQL query with full-text

Tags: mysql, optimization, full-text-search, innodb

I have 2 tables.

1. special_order (Orders table) - has 420 000 data
2. special_order_product (Products table) which linked with order_id to special_order table. has 1 000 000 data

Database storage engine: InnoDB

I tried to find orders which have products according to keyword with left join. The query takes 10-15 seconds. Also, I use the full-text index for product_link column other indexes(special_order.id, special_order_product.order_id)

SPECIAL_ORDER TABLE:
[Table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUdvJ.png)

SPECIAL ORDER PRODUCTS TABLE:
[Table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAkLk.png)

The query:

```
SELECT distinct(special_order.id), special_order.admin_id, special_order.user_id, 
  special_order.total_price, special_order.created_at, special_order.updated_at 
FROM special_order LEFT JOIN special_order_product 
  ON special_order.id = special_order_product.order_id 
WHERE MATCH(product_link) AGAINST ('trendyol' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
order by created_at desc limit 30
```

Result: 30 rows in set (15.730 sec)

Explain of query:
[Explain of the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLZO2.png)

Indexes over special_order table:
[Special order table indexes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvBXZ.png)

Indexes over special_order_product table:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4P7W.png)

Comment: right info, just really hard to read as links to images. `SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablename}` is an easier way to read table/index structure. sqlformat.org makes longer queries actually readable. Welcome to SO. This may get moved to dba.stackexchange.com. Hold tight, you can edit your question.

Comment: Can you add the query info to the question .

Comment: @danblack i added images as you want.

Comment: @Vidal added query info and explanation of query

Comment: Ambiguous -- both tables have `created_at`, so which one should it `ORDER BY`??

Answer (score 0):

- `DISTINCT` is not a function; it will dedup the set of `SELECT` columns.
- You seem to want to find `product_link` values, yet you say it is option (`LEFT`).  Perhaps `LEFT` is wrong?

Suggest rewriting thus:

```
SELECT  so.id, so.admin_id, so.user_id, so.total_price,
        so.created_at, so.updated_at
    FROM ( SELECT p.order_id 
             FROM special_order_product AS p
             WHERE  MATCH(p.product_link) AGAINST ('trendyol' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
             order by  p.created_at desc
             limit  30
         ) AS p2
    JOIN  special_order AS so  ON so.id = p2.order_id
    order by  so.created_at desc
```

Notes:

- The derived table (subquery) focuses on getting 30 items, then stopping.
- Hence, there are only 30 probes into `so`.
- I assume there is no need for de-duplicating.
- The `ORDER BY` is repeated (sort of) because the subquery has no order when used by the outer query.  But the `LIMIT` needs the data sorted.

Needed indexes (the others are not useful here):

```
p: FULLTEXT(product_link)
so: (id)  -- the PRIMARY KEY
```